# Can I specify which hostname to check an SSH certificate against?

Tags: ssh, certificates

I've set up an SSH certificate for `*.example.com`, but not yet got around to setting up CNAMEs. Rather than mapping hostnames to IPs in `/etc/hosts` (and subsequently forgetting about the CNAMEs), is it possible to tell the `ssh 192.0.2.4` command *directly* to treat `192.0.2.4` as `foo.example.com` for the purpose of certificate validation? Similar to setting the "Host" header in a cURL command to validate the certificate against that hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set up a HostKeyAlias in your `.ssh/config`.

> HostKeyAlias
>
> Specifies an alias that should be used instead of the real host name when looking
>    up or saving the host key in the host key database files.  This option is useful
>    for tunneling SSH connections or for multiple servers running on a single host.

So in your case, something like

```
Host 192.0.2.4
  HostKeyAlias foo.example.com
```